# Is it possible to automatically pre populate a column of excel

Tags: excel

Number------Automatic repeat of numbers

87638
10898
197981
339831
3809801

Hi guys, I am fresh to excel I am usually doing back end programming but for my work placement I am being asked to pre populate columns from curtains which is the system this Credit Union uses to store client details, I am being asked to pull values from the Curtain (Kesho System) and make it automatically increment into excel columns I don't know if its possible or not? I do know it is possible to pull information from the Curtain because I have created reports and letters pulling information from clients i.e. First Name , DOB etc. but I don't know if I can do this in excel? Anyway my main question is how can I automatically increment the numbers from the column 'Number' to  'Automatic Repeat Number' column? would that be possible ? The numbers are made up.

Comment: Do you need a random number? or a calculated number based on the column. No clear what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't find your question very clear. What do you mean by "automatic repeat of numbers"? Whatever your question actually is -- the answer to "would that be possible" is almost certainly "yes" if you use VBA and possibly "yes" if you don't.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see a pattern off-hand and don't have the time to research how you came up with those numbers. Additionally, the narrative detailing the expected results is a little sparse. But yes, you can do this in Excel.

Comment: yeah in the question how can I repeat the numbers from the 'Number' column and set them in the 'Automatic repeat numbers' column? Numbers are made up by the way, sorry I didnt know they have to be specific.

Comment: Do you mean is it possible to copy numbers from one column to another? Of course it is. What do you mean by doing it "automatically"? What is supposed to trigger this copying?

Comment: you're trying to integrate you Curtains system to excel?

Comment: Instead of copy and paste can the column Automatic Number column automatically update with the same numbers from the Number column? and happen everytime I add a data to the Number column.

Comment: yes extract some information from kesho system to excel.

Comment: You can simply select the columns you want to repeat the number, type `=IF(A1="","",A1)` and press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` to make an array formula, and then drag down for as many rows as you need (including extra rows to accommodate more data in the future).

Comment: Ohh I see, how can I do that but from one column in one sheet to another column in a different sheet?

Answer (score 0):

If the five numbers you show happened to be in C1:C5 of Sheet6 and you would like them copied into ColumnA of Sheet8 starting Row1, and any additions in C6 etc then automatically also copied into Sheet8 then in Sheet8 A1 and copied down to the end:

```
=IF(Sheet6!C1="","",Sheet6!C1)
```